# Youtube-data-api Get Playlist liked video

Tags: youtube-data-api

such by title, I need to get Liked video playlist from some channel id. I've used the call "Channel lists" for retrieve all playlist of user. In fact, I get correctly all playlist **except Id playlist of "liked video"**. Maybe is it impossible to get it? Can you help me please? Thank you so much...

Comment: What programming language are you using? Also, what have you tried in terms of code written?

Comment: Yes, of course. Anyway to python language. But , independently of programming language, I means that is it possible to get that playlist? maybe it's protected ? The response of call get me all my playlist except "liked video playlist". Do you know something about it? Thank again ( you see https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list )

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the list of liked videos only of the user authorizing the API request. So first, make sure you authorize your app to perform requests on behalf of the channel owner.

Once authorized, you can fetch the liked videos by querying against the [`Videos: list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint at `GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos` and setting the `myRating` parameter to `'like'`.

For example in python, it would be something like this:

```
response = client.videos().list({
    'part': 'snippet,contentDetails,statistics',
    'myRating': 'like'
}).execute()
```

A detailed example is also available at the YouTube Data API Developer guide under the [Usage](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#usage) section. Just choose “list (my liked videos)” from the *use cases* options.

Comment: Thanks, but it isn't the aswer that i want. Update: In some case, i get the id of liked video, but not in other. Do you know why? see here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels into voice ContentDetails->RelatedPlaylists->likes. Likes will be "id liked video".

Comment: I guess `likes` will be empty or not present if current user has no liked videos.

Comment: Not exactly. Sometimes it isn't present, sometimes is present. i don't know why.. I done some test and i don't find a reason. For example, i don't get my Playlist liked video ( the filed "likes" doesn't exist ) but from other account i get this information. Maybe is it a problem with old account and youtube api? (i've a playlist liked video of course )